# Dangers of NTFS compression?

Tags: ntfs, compression

What are the dangers of NTFS compression? Can I lose files? What if say my CPU, motherboard or PSU burns? What if some data on my HDD becomes corrupted?

Comment: We're here to help, but there appears to be little to no research done on this issue up front and/or there's very little for someone here to go on to assist you.  It is recommended that you post things you've already tried, options you are considering, or errors that you are experiencing.  The more details you provide (logs, screenshots, etc.), the better the experts here can assist you.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/173082/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-ntfs-compression

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be purely theoretical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no dangers of data loss, however compression and decompression takes CPU cycles to perform, so you're essentially making a trade of CPU cycles for disk space when compressing.  If data on your hard drive gets corrupted... it's going to be corrupted whether it's compressed or not.  And, of course, CPU, motherboard or PSU don't have anything to do with the data written on the drive, so those failing won't cause data loss, with or without NTFS compression.  Unless the hard drive catches fire too, or shorts out, or what have you.

[Best practices for NTFS compression in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/251186)

[Is it a good idea to use NTFS Compression?](https://superuser.com/questions/173082/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-ntfs-compression)

The only situation I can think of where there are "dangers" associated with NTFS compression would be on a SAN.  Those extra CPU cycles can cause nearly impossible to diagnose hangs and perfomance degradations.